# I have the guts of a VBA loop written, but I need help making it "infinite"

Tags: vba, excel

Probably a terrible explanation of my problem. Let me try explain better here.

I have a code written that will copy data from one range if certain conditions are met, or take data from another range if different conditions are met. At the moment, I could conceivably just continue the pattern already established in the macro below, but I don't think it would be wise to reach 100 or so with thousands of lines of code. What I have so far is as follows:

```
Sub Sort()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Dim Pub1 As Range
Dim Pub2 As Range
Dim Pub3 As Range
Dim Pub4 As Range
Dim Pub5 As Range
Dim Pub6 As Range

i = 2

While i <= 800
    Set Rng = Range("C" & i)
    Set Pub1 = Range("J" & i)
    Set Pub2 = Range("N" & i)
    Set Pub3 = Range("R" & i)
    Set Pub4 = Range("V" & i)
    Set Pub5 = Range("Z" & i)
    Set Pub6 = Range("AD" & i)

    If Rng.Offset(, 5) = "False" Then
        i = i + 1

    ElseIf Rng.Offset(, 5) = "" Then
        i = i + 1

    ElseIf Rng.Offset(, 5) = "True" And Pub2 = "" Then
        Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        i = i + 1

    ElseIf Rng.Offset(, 5) = "True" And Pub2 <> "" And Pub3 = "" Then
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 11).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        i = i + 2

    ElseIf Rng.Offset(, 5) = "True" And Pub3 <> "" And Pub4 = "" Then
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 11).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 15).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        i = i + 3

    ElseIf Rng.Offset(, 5) = "True" And Pub4 <> "" And Pub5 = "" Then
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 11).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 15).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 19).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        i = i + 4

    ElseIf Rng.Offset(, 5) = "True" And Pub5 <> "" And Pub6 = "" Then
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 11).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 15).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 19).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Rng.Offset(, 23).Resize(, 3).Copy
        Rng.Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        i = i + 5
    Else
        Stop
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

The script is already bloated as it is, and if I wanted to expand this to contain, say, Pub50 or Pub 60, I'd need to write a LOT more lines. Is it possible to insert some information to describe how, say, the column offset for copying will increase by 4 while the rows will increase by one, until a certain limit is reached?

The purpose of the code is to look along a long row of data and say, "If there are 4 entrants (Pub4 <> "" and Pub5 = "") then take the data and form 1 new row for each datapoint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Proper formatting in your code should be common practice. Makes it much easier to read. Can you show the input and expected output that this code is doing?

Comment: Judging from your code, I think you will have a tough time making this simple. What i would advise you to do, as a start, would be to create a function ( maybe recursive ?) to make the inside of you `if` somehow easier to manage. If you look quickly, just you just add 4 lines very similar to the previous ones, you should be able to make it recursive in no time. Once that part done, you might see clearer a path to simplify even more the rest of your code.

Comment: Welcome to writing your First Subroutine! You have to find the commonalities in your code and make those into parameters that you pass to your subroutine. Now you can loop as much as you want, over as many "Pubs" as you want and call the subroutine for each. There seem to be many commonalities, so it shouldn't be a problem. Give it a try, and if you have problems you can post them as other questions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie what makes you think it's their first subroutine? The user has posted in the excel-vba tag before.

Comment: I think it would help a lot to show a screenshot of your data.  It's difficult to come up with a generic solution where the structure is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick recursive subroutine to replace the inside of your `if - elseif`. It should at least reduce greatly the number of lines to code, as you can simply increment your argument to match the comportment of your function.

```
function recursive [(j,j)]
buffer = j % Line to add the i=i+1 at the end of your blocks%
if j=0 Then
    Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy;
    Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown;

    Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 3).Copy;
    Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues;
    buffer = buffer + 1;
else
    Rng.Offset(, -2).Resize(, 670).Copy;
    Rng.Offset(1, -2).Insert Shift:=xlDown;

    Rng.Offset(, 7+4*j).Resize(, 3).Copy;
    Rng.Offset(j,0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues;
    recursive [(j-1,buffer)];
end if
end recursive
```

It should work as expected. Of course it's just a step in the right direction, but it should make the rest easier to read at least. I don't usually code in VBA, but i don't think that the notations i used are wrong, tell me if i need to edit this if you see anything wrong.

I am however not sure that my "buffer" method is quite elegant, you might want to modify it at your will.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm quite new to VBA, so I'm not sure how to integrate this with my current code. Would I be having the main macro call this function for every time, say, Rng.Offset(, 5) = True?

Thanks!